# Localization of GUI built with Glade and Python (Gtk)

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, gettext, glade

I have made an application using Glade and Python and I would like to make several localizations.

I know how to localize strings that are in the Python code, I just encapsule all the strings that are supposed to be localized with _() and than specify the translation of the string in a .po file.

But how do I tell a string that is built with Glade that it should be localizable (for example labels, menu items, button labels, ...)?

I am using gettext for the localization.

Thank you, Tomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create a *.pot file from a *.glade file using `intltool-extract --type=gettext/glade foo.glade`, and `intltool` supposedly knows what is translatable.

Also, I suggest you look into GtkBuilder if you didn't do that already (you can save GtkBuilder interface files from recent Glade 3 versions, and you won't need the extra libglade anymore).

Comment: I believe `intltool` knows what is translatable in the `foo.glade` file thanks to the `translatable="yes"` properties. Example: `<object class="GtkButton" id="myButton"><property name="label" translatable="yes">This is my button</property>`